# How to change List<List<Items>> into a custom type

Tags: c#, .net

I'm planning on making a weekmenu. The weekmenu is a list of lists of recipes, the first list being the days, whereas the second list are 3 items some user can choose from to eat on that specific date.

Now some might say, having a `List<List<Items>` as a type might be hard to read. Some might not understand the reason for having a List of Lists. I would like to make that more readable. Maybe change it to something like `List<Weekday<Recipes>>`, which shows that there's a list of weekdays, and the weekdays containing recipes. How can I do that? Or is this not right to do it at all?

Comment: If you want an "OO" approach, or even a simple "Domain driven" design, You have several days, (so a `List<Weekday>`), and each `Weekday` _has_  a menu, which is a list of menu item  `List<MenuItem>`. In your current suggestion `List<Weekday<Recipes>>`, the recipe here is not a generic type parameter, you cannot have weekdays with recipes, and other weekdays with something else (as far as I understand)

Comment: What about a `Dictionary<Date, List<Recipe>>`?

Comment: Dictionary<Date, List<Recipe>> Date as a key is a bad example. I suggest that you do it as @Pac0 Suggested By OO

Comment: @Pac0 The, in your case MenuItems, are supposed to only be able to be recipes. So the user can for example, choose between 3 recipes that the user wants to eat for dinner. I was wondering how I can change the type from `List<List<Recipe>>` to `List<Weekday<Recipe>>`, where `Weekday` is the custom type.

Comment: A WeekMenu class, with your menuItens grupped by week day... something like:

class WeekMenu {
 List<MenuIten> Monday;
 List<MenuIten> Thursday;
 ...
}

Comment: I would find using `List<Weekday<Recipe>>` in which `Weekday`is basically an alias for `List` _extremely confusing_, much more than `List<List<Recipe>>`. However, you _can_ create a _simple alias_  for type name by using : `using WeekdayRecipes = List<Recipe>`, and then `List<WeekdayRecipes>` if you wish, that looks more readable than your suggestion. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive

Comment: how about a `Dictionary<DayOfWeek,List<Recipes>>`?, it would have more semantic value, i think. plus `DayOfWeek` is already part of .Net so it's compatible with DateTime and you could get it by `DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek`